# Creating special grid by using only flex functionalities

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have to create a layout which looks like:

[image: Red div, space, yellow div, blue div on the right side]

I've prepared code like:

```css
.red {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.yellow {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-self: end;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="red"> </div>
  <div class="yellow"> </div>
  <div class="blue"> </div>
</div>
```

But this blue div don't want to align to the right side:

[image: red div, space, yellow div, blue div]

Here you can a have a preview of that: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ncszob80/17/

I know that I can fix it with `margin-left: auto` css style for blue div.
But I'm wondering if there is some possibility of creating such layout only by using flex functionality.

So:

- we can use only flex functionalities
- there needs to be some margin between red div and yellow one
- blue div needs to be at the very right

How to achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS align one item right with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269947/css-align-one-item-right-with-flexbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You wrote:*

> I know that I can fix it with `margin-left: auto` css style for blue div. But I'm wondering if there is some possibility of creating such layout only by using flex functionality.

Actually, `margin-left: auto` is flex functionality. It's a feature of flex layout.

From the flexbox specification:

- [§ 8.1. Aligning with `auto`
  margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)

Also see:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

In summary, just use the `auto` margin. It's the cleanest, simplest and most efficient solution.

Comment: I had no idea it is a good solution to use the margin for such situations thanks for the clarification. Now I can use it without heart attack :D

Comment: It's a feature buried deep in the specification, but it's there... and it's very useful. See the second link for a more in-depth explanation and many examples.

Answer (score 1):

My best solution for you would be to change your DOM structure a little bit - but it accomplishes what you're looking for:

```css
.left {
  display: flex;
}
.red {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.yellow {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="red"> </div>
    <div class="yellow"> </div>
    </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="blue"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I wrapped your boxes in `.left` and `.right`, and then changed the `.wrapper` to `justify-content: space-between` so that the `.right` box is shoved to the right. Then, we make `.left { display: flex; }` to fix the issue with those boxes stacking without doing this, or changing the elements inside to `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested flex boxes. Make the flex wrapper for your blue item and justify that to the end:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}

.red {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.yellow {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blueWrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.blue {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="red"> </div>
  <div class="yellow"> </div>
  <div class="blueWrap">
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from changing your DOM structure or using the `margin-left: auto` fix CSS Grid is fantastic for this type of layout.  I know you said only Flexbox but if you don't want any of the other solutions Grid might be a nice alternative.  You can mix Flex functionality within the grid as well for finer control.  I do this regularly to achieve the layout I'm in need of and it works well!

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea if you don't want to consider `margin:auto` and without changing your html but like said in the accepted answer, margin is **a** feature of flexbox:

```css
.red {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.yellow {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  order:1; /*make the blue the last element*/
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content:"";
  flex-grow:1; /*make this hidden element to take all the space and push the blue*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="red"> </div>
  <div class="yellow"> </div>
  <div class="blue"> </div>
</div>
```